# "How to export azure test plan to pdf"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-automation, test-plan

I can't find button print to export test cases on test plan page.

[image]

I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops) there's button print like in this image

[image]

But my Azure don't have it.

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress

Comment: yes, its all because i don't purchase Basic + Test Plan feature. thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find button print to export test cases on test plan page.

I think this caused by your Test has been **expired** now. Does your **New Test Plan** button also could not be found?

For how to check whether **Test Plan** has expired, please go **Organization Setting -> Billing -> Boards, Repos and Test Plans**, and you will see the expired date of **Test Plan**:

[image]

And also, if you want to use this **Print** feature, you may need to purchase **Test Plan**. Click the icon beside test plan, you will see the detailed doc showed how to [purchase Test Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-plus-test-plans?view=azure-devops).

[image]